# ROS Answers SE migration: Pytest in ros2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I had never used `pytest` for `ros` before. I was looking for some examples of how to set up `pytest` and use `colcon test` to test it out. Inside `setup.py` for the packages I see `tests_require = ['pytest']` and also that pkg contains `test` and `resources` folder, but not sure how to use it. Some basic examples would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399986/pytest-in-ros2/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's an option in `colcon test` ([ref (colcon.readthedocs.io)](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/reference/verb/test.html#python-specific-arguments)):

```
--python-testing {pytest,setuppy_test}
```

Note that these are for "pure Python" test cases, i.e. tests that don't involve ROS nodes. For tests with ROS nodes, in ROS1 you can use [rostest](http://wiki.ros.org/rostest). In ROS2, #q292100 (started in 2018) indicates there's no equivalent.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2022-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1